# file_put_contents(D:\xampp\htdocs\toh-barcode\public\uploads\barcode): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel

I use the following code to save images from other URLs to my folder

```
<?php
  $string = "https://eandata.com/.../products/000/000/0000000000000.jpg";
  $img = public_path('uploads\barcode');
  file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($string));
?
```

it reports an error:"file_put_contents (D: \ xampp \ htdocs \ toh-barcode \ public \ uploads \ barcode): failed to open stream: denied permission."
How to fix bugs. Thanks all

Comment: error explaining itself. Set write permission for that file.

Comment: Has your webserver got the rights to write to that folder?

Comment: How to set permissions for a directory ?

Comment: This is genuine question people. . . not everyday you get permission error on windows localhost. So please don't down-vote immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to give the permission for the images folder by going to the Folder > Right click > properties and goes to Permission and then change all the permissions to read&write

Answer (score 0):

First please change to **uploads/barcode** insteads of **uploads\barcode**
Then please makesure the path uploads/barcode has been created.

```
$path = 'uploads/barcode';
if (!file_exists($path)) {
    mkdir('uploads/barcode');
}
```

If still not work please change permissions of the foder to Read & Write:

Linux or Mac OS

```
chmod -R 777
```

Windowns

```
Going to the Folder > Right click > properties and goes to Permission and then change all the permissions to Read & Write
```